# exporting some infos from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

i used this library https://pypi.org/project/python-codicefiscale/.
i have already a dataframe with 2 existing columns (user_id and tax_code), i wanna add 2 new columns :

- first one is a column called name that gives me back the name of the city decoding the tax code of my row
  -second one is a column called province that gives me back the province that i extract from this decoding

```
codicefiscale.decode('CCCFBA85D03L219P')

# {
#     'code': 'CCCFBA85D03L219P',
#     'sex': 'M',
#     'birthdate': datetime.datetime(1985, 4, 3, 0, 0),
#     'birthplace': {
#         'name': 'TORINO'
#         'province': 'TO',
#         'code': 'L219',
#     },
#     'omocodes': [
#         'CCCFBA85D03L219P',
#         'CCCFBA85D03L21VE',
#         'CCCFBA85D03L2MVP',
#         'CCCFBA85D03LNMVE',
#         'CCCFBA85D0PLNMVA',
#         'CCCFBA85DLPLNMVL',
#         'CCCFBA8RDLPLNMVX',
#         'CCCFBAURDLPLNMVU',
#     ],
#     'raw': {
#         'code': 'CCCFBA85D03L219P',
#         'surname': 'CCC',
#         'name': 'FBA',
#         'birthdate': '85D03',
#         'birthdate_year': '85'
#         'birthdate_month': 'D',
#         'birthdate_day': '03',
#         'birthplace': 'L219',
#         'cin': 'P',
#     },
# }
```

i have no clue how to extract them from the dictionary and passing every row of my database.
i tried a function like this:

```
from codicefiscale import codicefiscale

def valid(row):
    tax_code = row[1]
    if tax_code.codicefiscale.is_valid():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: what is `codicefiscale` it is not defined ?  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: did you mean to put this at the top of the code:   `from codicefiscale import codicefiscale`...  or was the import meant to be nested in a function ?

Comment: Yeah i didnt remember to say that i imported this library https://pypi.org/project/python-codicefiscale/

Comment: What is it you want tp extract?   `codicefiscale.decode('CCCFBA85D03L219P')['birthplace']['province']` will return "TO" from that entry.